# Excel 2010 Formula Array Shortcut not working

Tags: excel, keyboard-shortcuts

I know the formula array shortcut is CTRL + Shift + Enter. For some reason this isn't working for me.

My cursor is in the formula bar when I am using the shortcut. I know the cell I'm applying it to is able to be a formula array, I received the Excel file with the cell as a formula array but can't apply it elsewhere with the same formula.

Does my cell have to be formatted a certain way for this to work? Or is there any other way I can get an array formula?

Comment: If you open a brand new workbook, can you create an array-entered formula in the new workbook? If you restart your computer, can you still not array-enter formulas? Make sure workbook and sheet are not protected and that calculation is set to automatic, but that's a really weird issue.  Perhaps an add-in could be causing it to fail? Could try Excel in safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

> "My cursor is in the cell when I am using the shortcut."

Place your cursor in the *Formula Bar* by clicking in the *Formula Bar.*

then touch:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Sorry, I did mean formula bar and not cell. It does not work when my cursor is in the formula bar.

Comment: @M.Daly If you touch the three keys sequentially, it will not work...........if the cell is formatted as *Text*, it will not work........

Comment: The cell format is number, I am presing the keys at the same time, the cell is not locked.